# How to keep a multi layer b-collapse menu open on re-fresh in VUE.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I'm struggling to find the best way to keep my multi-layer menu open on re-fresh.

Basically if someone drills down to the third layer in my menu and clicks re-fresh, then I want the menu to open back up to where they navigated to in the third layer without having to re-open the menu.

Please see my code below: (Using Vue-Bootstrap and Vue.js)

As you can see, I'm repeating over each layer I get from my data.

```html
        <div v-for="(main, index) in mainMenu" :key="index">
          <template v-if="main.title === 'News'">
            <b-link @click="closeAll" v-if="main.type === 'post_type' " :to="'/' + main.slug" v-b-toggle="'collapse'"  class="m-1 nobutn" v-html="main.title"></b-link>
          </template>
          <template v-else>
            <b-link v-if="main.type === 'post_type' " :to="'/' + main.slug" v-b-toggle="main.post_name" class="m-1 nobutn" v-html="main.title"></b-link>
            <b-link v-else :to="'/' + main.url" v-b-toggle="main.post_name" class="m-1 nobutn" v-html="main.title"></b-link>
          </template>
          <b-collapse v-model="main.show" v-for="(sub, index) in main.child_items" :key="index" v-bind:id="sub.menu_item_parent" accordion="my-accordion" role="tabpanel">
            <template v-if="sub.type === 'post_type'">
              <b-link class="secondLayer" :to="'/' + main.slug + '/' + sub.slug" :class="sub.classes">
                <b-card v-b-toggle="sub.post_name" class="subTitle" v-html="sub.title"></b-card>
              </b-link>
            </template>
            <template v-else>
              <b-link :href="sub.url" target="_blank" :class="sub.classes">
                <b-card v-b-toggle="sub.post_name" class="subTitle" v-html="sub.title"></b-card>
              </b-link>               
            </template>
            <b-collapse v-for="(subchild, index) in sub.child_items" :key="index" v-bind:id="subchild.menu_item_parent" accordion="my-accordiontwo" role="tabpanel">
              <template v-if="subchild.title === 'Members Portal' ">
                <b-link class="thirdLayer" :href="subchild.url" target="_blank" :class="subchild.classes">
                  <b-card v-b-toggle="subchild.post_name" class="subchildTitle" v-html="subchild.title"></b-card>
                </b-link>
              </template>
              <template v-else>
                <b-link class="thirdLayer" :to="'/' + main.slug + '/' + sub.slug + '/' + subchild.slug" :class="subchild.classes">
                  <b-card v-b-toggle="subchild.post_name" class="subchildTitle" v-html="subchild.title"></b-card>
                </b-link>
              </template>
              <b-collapse v-for="(fourthsubchild, index) in subchild.child_items" :key="index" :id="fourthsubchild.menu_item_parent">
                <b-link class="fouthLayer" :to="'/' + main.slug + '/' + sub.slug + '/' + subchild.slug + '/' + fourthsubchild.slug" :class="fourthsubchild.classes">
                  <b-card class="fourthchildTitle" v-html="fourthsubchild.title"></b-card>
                </b-link>
              </b-collapse>
            </b-collapse>
          </b-collapse>
        </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A detailled answer is hard, because I don't know your setup and am not familliar with vue-bootstrap.

It could look something like this in your components setup function:

```
onBeforeMount(() => {
  const thirdMenu = sessionStorage.getItem("thirdMenu");
  if (thirdMenu) {
    yourVariableWhatMenuIsOpen = thirdMenu; // open your third level menu as you want
  }
});

watch(
  () => yourVariableWhatMenuIsOpen,
  () => {
    yourVariableWhatMenuIsOpen
      ? sessionStorage.setItem("key", yourVariableWhatMenuIsOpen)
      : sessionStorage.removeItem("key");
  }
);
```

`yourVariableWhatMenuIsOpen` is something you probably have initialized for your menu.
Instead of a [watcher](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html) you could use a [reactive state](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html#simple-state-management-with-reactivity-api).

Hope, this helps. Maybe you have to dig a bit deeper into Vue, but it will be all fun, I promise. :)

Answer (score 0):

A page refresh sets back your whole page.
You could save a boolean e. g. *menuIsOpen* in your [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).
Set the value when the menu is opened and before your component is mounted, try to get the key-value from the session storage. If it's available, set the menu to open again.

**Edit:** Sorry, for a dynamic third layer you should save a string or id rather than a boolean. ;)

Comment: Thank you @zero2579

Is there anyway you could give me an example of what you have described above. I'm still new to Vue.js.